# Chef: How to subscribe to any file in a directory?

Tags: resources, chef-infra

While it is rather easy to `subscribe` a chef provider to a single file (e.g. `subscribes :restart, 'template[/etc/daemon/foo.conf]`, I am struggling to find some mechanism where I can subscribe to any file in a directory. Basically, what I am looking for is some sort of regex/wildcard matching, like `subscribes :restart, 'template[/etc/daemon/*]`.

The use case here is a `conf.d` mechanism, so I want to reload php after any new file is placed in `/etc/php/conf.d`. I can not use `notifies` from the recipe, since I do not know in the respective php modules if there is just php-cli, php-fpm or mod_php with apache to notify.

The only way I can come up with is creating some weird hack, like modifying an arbitrary `/etc/php/modulelist.txt` by each php module, and subscribing to that one, but maybe there is a better/nicer way using Chef.

Comment: Maybe you can parse the ressource hash to get a list of subscriptions to do, obvisouly they have to be defined before your subscribing ressource

Comment: Looping over the resource collection? (see [here](https://sethvargo.com/changing-chef-resources-at-runtime/) . But in general, the part that has an influence, i.e., the resource that places a config file there, should notify the service.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array of your templates and pass this array to service

```rb
templates = ['template[/t1]', 'tempalte[/t2]']
subscribes :restart, templates, :delayed
```